# How to connect JavaScript with Tableau view?

Tags: javascript, api, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau. I have a task to connect a speedometer code written in javascript 
with tableau dashboard. The code will take excel sheet as input and according to that
the dashboard should modify. I know it has something to do with javascript API, but I need 
some help. It should work something like this link given below
http://mkt.tableausoftware.com/community/page/TablesInTheEastGame/TITETG.html

Appreciate any suggestion on how to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2):

Consider starting with the Javascript API overview
http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#js_api.htm

And this very clear interactive tutorial
http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm